# Connecting to Database (Postgres AWS RDS)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am following the tutorial on how to set up and connect a PostgreSQL server on AWS found [HERE](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/)

When I try to sign in on workbench, I get this message:[image]

At first I thought it was because my DB instance was not available yet, so I waited until it finished backing up. This did not seem to work as I am still getting this message. I will appreciate assistance on this.

Comment: If voters could add comments explaining why they have down voted, so that I can improve future questions. Thanks

Comment: were you able to solve issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created a secutiry group and allow databases connection port?

From the docs:

> `VPC Security Group(s): Select Create New Security Group. This will
>   create a security group that will allow connection from the IP address
>   of the device you are currently using, to the database created.`